# Unable to build pymqi on window - errors compiling

Tags: python, gcc, build, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am trying to build and install pymqi, but I am getting a lot of errors trying to compile it.

I have done the following:

Get and install MinGW gcc

Create libpython2?.a

Using instruction from: https://pythonhosted.org/pymqi/mingw32.html

When I try to build it using: `setup.py build -cmingw32 client`
I get a list of undefined references. Below are some examples

```
build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\pymqe.o:pymqe.c:(.text+0x25e): undefined  reference to `MQINQMP'
build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\pymqe.o:pymqe.c:(.text+0x463): undefined reference to `MQSETMP'
```

At the very end, I also get the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp
.win32-2.6\Release\pymqe.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using:

- Python 26
- gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

Any clues and help will be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have WebSphere MQ v7.0 or higher installed on the server where you are doing the build.  Also, when you did the installation of MQ, did you include the "Development Toolkit"?  It is optional and you need to select it.

Comment: Thanks, how would I check if I have the development toolkit installed?
btw i have MQ V 7.5 installed